# Align text next to the upper left corner of a node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have two nodes below each other:

```
\documentclass[DIN, pagenumber=false, fontsize=11pt, parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt, nodes={outer sep=0pt, minimum width=3cm, thick, minimum height=1cm}]

\node (n1) at (3,2) [draw, minimum height=2cm] {n1};
\node (n2)  [draw, below=of n1.south] {n2};
\node[left=of n1](t1) {this is a label};
\node[minimum width=0cm, left=of t1] {foo};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to add two adjoining labels next to the upper left corner of each node. These now lines place the labels next to node `n1`, but I cannot push it upwards to the corner.

```
\node[left=of n1](t1) {this is a label};
\node[minimum width=0cm, left=of t1] {foo};
```

This is how the upper code looks like:
[image]

And this is how it should like:
[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example (that can be compiled).

Comment: Yep, I have just added the necessary code.

Comment: It doesn't compile.

Comment: sry...again....this time copy&paste worked...

Comment: Hmmm, okay. Unless it is really needed for your question (not the case here), you should use the `article` class (in some cases, `standalone` also makes sense) and **pass no options** to it when preparing a minimal working example. Please see the tips [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `anchor=east, left=of n1.north west` for that:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt, nodes={outer sep=0pt, minimum width=3cm, thick, minimum height=1cm}]
\node (n1) at (3,2) [draw, minimum height=2cm] {n1};
\node (n2)  [draw, below=of n1.south] {n2};
\node[anchor=east, left=of n1.north west] (t1) {this is a label};
\node[minimum width=0cm, left=of t1] {foo};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

In order to flush the `t1` node completely against `n1`, or to adjust the space between them, don't apply `minimum width=3cm` to `t1` and use something like `inner xsep=0, left=0cm of n1.north west` in its options. Example with a null separator (`left=0cm of n1.north west`):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt,
                    nodes={outer sep=0pt, thick, minimum height=1cm}]

\begin{scope}[minimum width=3cm]
  \node (n1) at (3,2) [draw, minimum height=2cm] {n1};
  \node (n2)  [draw, below=of n1.south] {n2};
\end{scope}

\node[inner xsep=0, anchor=east, left=0cm of n1.north west] (t1)
  {this is a label};
\node[minimum width=0cm, left=of t1] {foo};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I have expanded my answer to show how you can tune the separator space.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for external nodes to put these labels. `labels` can be used for this. You just need to select the correct anchor and position. It's even possible to declare `labels` for `labels`. But take care when declaring styles for `nodes` because `labels` are also `nodes`.

```
\documentclass[DIN, pagenumber=false, fontsize=11pt, parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=0pt, 
    box/.style={draw, outer sep=0pt, minimum width=3cm, thick, minimum height=1cm}]

\node[box, minimum height=2cm, 
    label={[name=t1, anchor=east, 
        label={[anchor=east]west:foo}]
            north west:this is a label}] 
    (n1) at (3,2) {n1};
\node[box, below=of n1.south] (n2) {n2};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]